# How to draw a rectangle on SVG with mouse move?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, canvas

I found code on someone's [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/richardcwc/ukqhf54k/) to stroke on mouse move (click and move strokes). My requirement is to stroke rectangle on a SVG with mouse move in the same way. Is it possible, if yes, how?

```js
//Canvas
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
//Variables
let canvasx = canvas.offsetLeft;
let canvasy = canvas.offsetTop;
let last_mousex = 0;
let last_mousey = 0;
let mousex = 0;
let mousey = 0;
let mousedown = false;

//Mousedown
canvas.onmousedown = ({
  clientX,
  clientY
}) => {
  last_mousex = parseInt(clientX - canvasx);
  last_mousey = parseInt(clientY - canvasy);
  mousedown = true;
};

//Mouseup
canvas.onmouseup = () => mousedown = false;


//Mousemove

canvas.onmousemove = ({
  clientX,
  clientY
}) => {
  mousex = parseInt(clientX - canvasx);
  mousey = parseInt(clientY - canvasy);
  if (mousedown) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); //clear canvas
    ctx.beginPath();
    const width = mousex - last_mousex;
    const height = mousey - last_mousey;
    ctx.rect(last_mousex, last_mousey, width, height);
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    ctx.stroke();
  }
};
```

```css
canvas {
  cursor: crosshair;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>

  <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="500"></canvas>

</body>

</html>
```

```
Some Code// To prevent Stackoverflow error, please ignore
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweaked Jason's answer to create rect element on the fly

```js
const svg = document.querySelector('#svg');
const svgNS = svg.namespaceURI;
const rect = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'rect');

let last_mousex = 0;
let last_mousey = 0;
let mousex = 0;
let mousey = 0;
let mousedown = false;

//Mousedown
svg.onmousedown = ({
  x,
  y
}) => {
  last_mousex = x;
  last_mousey = y;
  mousedown = true;
};

//Mouseup
svg.onmouseup = () => mousedown = false;

//Mousemove
svg.onmousemove = ({
  x,
  y
}) => {
  mousex = parseInt(x);
  mousey = parseInt(y);
  if (mousedown) {
    const width = Math.abs(mousex - last_mousex);
    const height = Math.abs(mousey - last_mousey);
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', last_mousex);
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', last_mousey);
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', width);
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', height);
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', "none");
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', "black");
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-width', 5);



    // svg.innerHTML = "";
    svg.appendChild(rect);
  }
};
```

```css
svg {
  cursor: crosshair;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="800" height="500">
</svg>
```

Answer (score 10):

In order to fully mimic the behavior of the `canvas` approach that enables you to draw a rectangle by clicking and dragging in any direction (i.e. lower right to top left or vice versa), you need to conditionally handle the x, y, width, and height values based on the position of the current mouse coordinates relative to the point of the initial `mousedown`. In addition, the snippet below includes a function that returns the correct coordinates if you are "drawing" on a transformed SVG element (or transformed child element).

```js
const svg = document.querySelector('#svg');
const svgPoint = (elem, x, y) => {
  const p = svg.createSVGPoint();
  p.x = x;
  p.y = y;
  return p.matrixTransform(elem.getScreenCTM().inverse());
};

svg.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
  const rect = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'rect');
  const start = svgPoint(svg, event.clientX, event.clientY);
  const drawRect = (e) => {
    const p = svgPoint(svg, e.clientX, e.clientY);
    const w = Math.abs(p.x - start.x);
    const h = Math.abs(p.y - start.y);
    if (p.x > start.x) {
      p.x = start.x;
    }

    if (p.y > start.y) {
      p.y = start.y;
    }

    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', p.x);
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', p.y);
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', w);
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', h);
    svg.appendChild(rect);
  };

  const endDraw = (e) => {
    svg.removeEventListener('mousemove', drawRect);
    svg.removeEventListener('mouseup', endDraw);
  };
  
  svg.addEventListener('mousemove', drawRect);
  svg.addEventListener('mouseup', endDraw);
});
```

```css
svg {
  cursor: crosshair;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

rect {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000000;
  stroke-width: 10;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="800" height="500"></svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing @benvc

Answer (score 3):

```js
const svg = document.querySelector('#svg');
const rect = document.querySelector('#rect');

let last_mousex = 0;
let last_mousey = 0;
let mousex = 0;
let mousey = 0;
let mousedown = false;

//Mousedown
svg.onmousedown = ({
  x,
  y
}) => {
  last_mousex = x;
  last_mousey = y;
  mousedown = true;
};

//Mouseup
svg.onmouseup = () => mousedown = false;

//Mousemove
svg.onmousemove = ({
  x,
  y
}) => {
  mousex = parseInt(x);
  mousey = parseInt(y);
  if (mousedown) {
    const width = Math.abs(mousex - last_mousex);
    const height = Math.abs(mousey - last_mousey);
    rect.setAttribute('x', last_mousex);
    rect.setAttribute('y', last_mousey);
    rect.setAttribute('width', width);
    rect.setAttribute('height', height);
    rect.style.fill = "none";
    rect.style.stroke = "black";
    rect.style['stroke-width'] = 5;
    svg.innerHTML = "";
    svg.appendChild(rect);
  }
};
```

```css
svg {
  cursor: crosshair;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="800" height="500">
  <rect id="rect"></rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: Clicking and dragging to the top-left doesn't work: it only draws the rectangle in the right/down directions with reference to the original position.